# Browse list of ALL of a class's variables in XCode 5's debugger?

Tags: debugging, xcode5

I've been frustrated lately with the fact that when stopped at a breakpoint in XCode 5's debugger, the list of variables for a class does not show all the ones in the class. For instance, SplitViewController only shows UIViewController as its only contents.

I've noticed however if in the console I type "po self.myVariable." (notice the . it ends with) then an autocomplete dialog pops up with a complete listing of all variables, including ones inherited from parent classes... exactly what I'm looking for, but hard to read since you can only see about 5 of these at a time in the tiny non-resizable pop-up window.

Is there a setting somewhere that I can enable to make all these values show up in the class list XCode shows on the left? (The ones where you expand classes by clicking the triangle.)

Comment: Does changing the scope under the class list in the debugger help at all?

Comment: Try `p * self.myVariable`.

Comment: @macshome -- unfortunately no. Expanding the scope list to maximum does not help.

Answer (score 1):

In the lower left corner of the debug panel there is a multi-choice selector that controls the variables displayed when stopped. The default state is "**Auto**", which I think tends to mean recently modified, and probably what yours would be set to.  You can change it to "**Local Variables**" or "**All Variables, Globals, Registers, and Statics**".